# Sharepoint 2010: How to set default value for a lookup column (no code)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to set default value for a lookup column (not in code) when user adds an item in a SP 2010 list?
Is there any other out of box solution/work around?

Comment: how do you create the column? via ihm, via a feature or via code ? do you have access to the powershell console ?

Comment: @Steve - I created the list and the columns using the web UI aka SharePoint site.

Comment: If you know of any other alternative solution, please add it to the answers (will mark it as answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd find a solution and just blogged about it. See it [***here***](http://kenkumar.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-set-default-value-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

View this add-on([SharePoint Default Value Add-On](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint_default_value)), which inject a "default value" section into "Create Column" dialog.

[image]